# Count number of distinct values based on another set of distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, counting

I am trying to count a set of values based on another distinct value set:

```
-----------------------------------------------------    
|CusID  |Agent1  |Agent2 |Agent 3 |Agent 4 |Agent 5 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|1      |Pat     |Pat    |Jane    |Simon   |Jane    |
|2      |Pater   |Pat    |Simon   |Simon   |Pat     |
|1      |Jane    |Jane   |Simon   |Pat     |Pat     |
|3      |Simon   |Simon  |Jane    |Pat     |Peter   |
|3      |Jane    |Simon  |Pat     |Pater   |Pat     |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|CusIDUnq  |AgentName|Count|AgentName|Count|AgentName|Count|AgentName|Count|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1         |Pat      |4    |Jane     |4    |Simon    |2    |Peter    |0    |
|2         |Pat      |2    |Jane     |0    |Simon    |2    |Pater    |1    |
|3         |Pat      |3    |Jane     |2    |Simon    |3    |Peter    |2    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I do this using SQL?

Thanks in advance!

edit:
I need to tell that the number of customers and agents could change over time. So, I think a solution like below is also fine with me. The point is, I can't code the agent names or customer IDs into the query.

```
-----------------------
|CusID|AgentName|Count|
-----------------------
|1    |Pat      |4    |
|1    |Jane     |4    |
|1    |Simon    |2    |
|2    |Pat      |2    |
|2    |Simon    |2    |
|2    |Peter    |1    |
```

etc.
Here, I need to omit 0 results where an agent is not listed for a specific customer.

Again, many thanks!

Comment: If you want a general solution which can support any number of agent names (e.g. more than 4, which is what your current data set has), then you'll need to delve into using dynamic SQL.  In any case, please tell us which database you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.).

Comment: thats a good question

Comment: And how are these `count` values defined?  The logic is not clear.

Comment: Can you provide sample data for the input and output?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Its the count of the number of times 'Pat' (or whatever) appears in any of the Agent fields for that ID

Comment: Thanks, everybody. The number of agents and customers could change over time so I need to have a solution that can count without any data elements coded in the query itself. Edited the question to reflect that and new solution type.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That is exactly what I need to do. I am using SQL Server 13.0 and accessing using SQL Server Management Studio 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data model a cus record has exactly five agents and there is a priority (or timeline or the like) of agents, with one agent being Agent1, one agent being Agent2, and so on.

In your query, however, you don't want to treat the agents differently, you don't even care whether they stem from the same cus row. In order to treat them all alike, we'll convert your table to a mere cus-agent table where each row has a pair of cus and agent. Then we can simply aggregate and count.

```
select cusid, agent, count(*)
from
(
  select cusid, agent1 as agent from mytable
  union all
  select cusid, agent2 as agent from mytable
  union all
  select cusid, agent3 as agent from mytable
  union all
  select cusid, agent4 as agent from mytable
  union all
  select cusid, agent5 as agent from mytable
) cus_agent
group by cusid, agent
order by cusid, agent;
```

If you want separate columns rather than rows for the agents, then use above query and care about the layout in your GUI layer (i.e. use a loop in your app or Website).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you can do:

```
select id,
       sum(case when 'Pat' in (Agent1, Agent2, Agent3, Agent4, Agent5)
                then 1 else 0 end
           end) as num_pat,
       sum(case when 'Jane' in (Agent1, Agent2, Agent3, Agent4, Agent5)
                then 1 else 0 end
           end) as num_jane,
       sum(case when 'Simon' in (Agent1, Agent2, Agent3, Agent4, Agent5)
                then 1 else 0 end
           end) as num_simon,
       sum(case when 'Peter' in (Agent1, Agent2, Agent3, Agent4, Agent5)
                then 1 else 0 end
           end) as num_peter
from t
group by id;
```

This puts the counts in column names with the agent name, but that seems to be what you want.

Comment: so close to your answer but still i think something more needs to be added in the query can check my answer and suggest to what i may be missing. i guess in my answer i need to add case statement in count as well like `count( Case when Agent1='Pat' then Agent1)` i think it should work without case but still unsure

Answer (score 1):

After messing the logic I have got some result as below query

```
     SELECT CUST_ID, 'Pat'
     Case when 'Pat' IN (Agent1,Agent2,
       Agent3,Agent4,Agent5)
      then 
      count(Agent1)+count(Agent2)+
         count(Agent3)+count(Agent4)+
          count(Agent5)
           else 0;
        End As 'Count_Pat',
      'Jane',

       Case when 'Jane' IN 
       (Agent1,Agent2,
       Agent3,Agent4,Agent5)
      then 
      count(Agent1)+count(Agent2)+
         count(Agent3)+count(Agent4)+
          count(Agent5)
           else 0;
        End as 'Count_Jane',
    'Simon',
     Case when 'Simon' IN 
       (Agent1,Agent2,
       Agent3,Agent4,Agent5)
      then 
      count(Agent1)+count(Agent2)+
         count(Agent3)+count(Agent4)+
          count(Agent5)
           else 0;
        End As 'Count_Simon',
         'Peter',
     Case when 'Peter' IN 
       (Agent1,Agent2,
       Agent3,Agent4,Agent5)
      then 
      count(Agent1)+count(Agent2)+
         count(Agent3)+count(Agent4)+
          count(Agent5)
           else 0;
        End as 'Count_Peter',

       From Table 

       group by cust_id;
```